# Altering Order of tables in JOIN condition

Tags: sql, join

Given the below scenario:

Table A has 1000 rows and Table B has 5000 rows.

> Q1: Select * from Table_A Left Outer Join Table_B 
>   ON *condition*
>
> Q2: Select * from Table_B Left Outer Join Table_A 
>   ON *condition*

Does this make any difference ? Would there be any performance difference in these situations?

Comment: Which database are you using? MS Access?

Comment: Hi John, 
I am asking this for any database.

Comment: Performance is DBMS-specific, so we cannot answer that part of it unless you tell us which one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it makes a *big* difference for a `LEFT JOIN`.  The two statements are not the same, and the execution paths are likely to be different.

The first query keeps all rows in Table A, plus any matching values from Table B.  So this version returns at least 1000 rows.

The second keeps all rows in Table B, plus any matching values from Table A.  This is not the same thing.  This version returns at least 5000 rows.

For an `INNER JOIN` (or `FULL OUTER JOIN`) then the order of the tables in the `FROM` clause does not affect the result set.  However, depending on the optimizer it could affect how the joins are processed (I am thinking of long chains of joins where optimizers take short-cuts).

Answer (score 0):

> Does this make any difference ?

Yes it does. `LEFT JOIN` Definition: returns all rows from left table + matching rows in both table. Matching row means intersection of both tables.

So in your case, the number of rows returned will be very different.

```
Q1: Select * from Table_A Left Outer Join Table_B ON condition
```

In this case number of rows returned will be `1000` (since your `tableA` has 1000 rows and in left side of `JOIN`) plus the match (intersection between the tables)

```
Q2: Select * from Table_B Left Outer Join Table_A ON condition
```

In this case number of rows returned will be `5000` (since your `tableB` has 5000 rows and in left side of `JOIN`) plus the match (intersection between the tables)

See the visual representation of the same [Image taken from [This CodeProject Post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)]:

[image]

Comment: thanks :) but would there be any considerable performance difference here..? The table with less rows being on left fetched faster??

Answer (score -1):

The two queries will have in different results.

See [W3 Schools Left Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

and go to the Try It Yourself page. The SQL can be edited for a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: thanks for the explaination. but would there be any considerable performance difference here..? The table with less rows being on left fetched faster??

Comment: Please don't quote W3 Schools. They are notorious for inaccurate information. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com.

Comment: I directed him to the Try It Yourself page which would allow the OP to try out and see for himself the differences. That was my intention.